# php DateTime from today and timestamp not identical

Tags: php, datetime

why DateTime created from the word "today" and timestamp representing "today" are not identical ?

```
$zone = 'US/Eastern';
$str = 'today';

$dt_zone = new DateTimeZone($zone);
$myDateTime = new DateTime($str, $dt_zone);

$my_stamp = $myDateTime->getTimestamp();

echo "from $my_stamp {$zone}:".$myDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "<br>";
```

we got result: from 1383886800 US/Eastern:08-11-2013 00:00:00

now lets create the same code but generate DateTime from the received timestamp:

```
$zone = 'US/Eastern';
$str = '@1383886800';

$dt_zone = new DateTimeZone($zone);
$myDateTime = new DateTime($str, $dt_zone);

$my_stamp = $myDateTime->getTimestamp();

echo "from $my_stamp {$zone}:".$myDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "<br>";
```

and we got DIFFERENT result but with the same timestamp:
we got result: from 1383886800 US/Eastern:08-11-2013 05:00:00

may be exists another way of creating datetime object from the timestamp ? 
To which i can later implement 
$myDateTime->modify('2 pm'); and receive modified timestamp 
(dont know how, coz $myDateTime->getTimestamp() return timestamp BEFORE modification )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it is better/nicer solution to input timestamp like you already done it in you 2nd example, instead of the use of method `setTimestamp`. All you need to do is set timezone on that DateTime object, with the call of `setTimezone` method, like [this demo](https://eval.in/64200).

```php
$myDateTime = new DateTime('@1383886800');
$myDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));
```

The reason why timezone is ignored, when creating DateTime object, is because when applying UNIX timestamp as input, default timezone UTC is used and supplied timezone is ignored. [See note at $timezone parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

```
The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $time 
parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone 
(e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's ignoring your timezone.. The manual has a comment about that. But there is a method for setting the timestamp. Which will have in the expected result

```
$zone = 'US/Eastern';

$dt_zone = new DateTimeZone($zone);
$myDateTime = new DateTime(null, $dt_zone);

$myDateTime->setTimestamp(1383886800); // Set from timestamp

$my_stamp = $myDateTime->getTimestamp();

echo "from $my_stamp {$zone}:".$myDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "\n";
```